# count id which are smaller than certain value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

My data consists of unique ids with a certain distance to a point. The goal is to count the id which is
equal or smaller than the radius.

Following example shows my DataFrame:

```
id    distance  radius
111   0.5       1
111   2         1
111   1         1
222   1         2
222   3         2
333   5         3
333   4         3
```

The output should look like this:

```
id  count
111 2
222 1
333 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
df['distance'].le(df['radius']).groupby(df['id']).sum()
```

Output:

```
id
111    2.0
222    1.0
333    0.0
dtype: float64
```

Or you can do:

```
(df.loc[df.distance <= df.radius, 'id']
   .value_counts()
   .reindex(df['id'].unique(), fill_value=0)
)
```

Output:

```
111    2
222    1
333    0
Name: id, dtype: int64
```